# windows batch, redirect cmd start, capture both stdout and error

Tags: batch-file

In need to start some command and capture both it's stdout and stderr in a log file.

```
start cmd /c myprogram.exe ^> log.txt 2>&1
```

But in log.txt are not printed stderr, instead they goes to the newly started shell.

In addition, the how can I print something in the new shell like "Please wait..."

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

If your complex command is not quoted, then all special characters must be escaped.

```
start cmd /c echo blabla ^& echo test ^& my_command ^> log.txt 2^>^&1"
```

Comment: I tried, but was not working, perhaps I missed some escape... tnx

Comment: @user1973900 - In your OP you forgot to escape the redirection of stderr: you need `2^>^&1` instead of `2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to display please wait it would be written as:

```
    echo Please Wait...
```

Comment: If it is a new shell that has not been used by a batch code I believe you can't do anything. A alternative is to open your file in a new shell if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found'it, sorry for such dumb question. At least on XP multiple commands must be quoted.
Log working too now for both err + out.

```
start cmd /c "echo blabla & echo test & my_command > log.txt 2>&1"
```